# Push notification not showing on android in foreground mode only for the first time

Tags: android, amazon-sns, android-push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I am facing some weird behaviour on showing push notification on android using FCM.

- When I am using app in foreground mode - Received notification silently but no message/title in notification bar.
- But in other modes like background/inactive its showing notification and working fine.
- When at-least 1 time notification delivered in background/inactive mode and then went to foreground of application, I am getting push notification as expected.

So just wondering why it is not working on the 1st instance of foreground.

I am trying with below payload:

```
{"GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"title_loc_key\": \"some_title\", \"body_loc_key\": \"some_description\", \"body_loc_args\": [\"120\"] }, \"priority\": \"high\" }"}
```

FYI.. I am using FCM setup and sending from AWS push SNS.